# Axon amqp messaging, event handler not triggered

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, axon

So im working on my first Axon application. So far I got the entire axon project working in the monolith. After that i started to divide the application into pieces using the @Profile from Sprint Boot. Also worked like a charm. So my next step is to go fully distributed and use 2 entirely different intellij projects for my Axon flow. And here i bump into a problem. I use AMQP for the messaging of the events. With the information in the docs i can get a event from one service to the other. But the eventhandler is not triggered. I guess the problems is because of the type of the Event. The first services sends the event like the following: **com.departureExample.Departure.coreapi.events.CheckIn.CheckedInEvent**. But my eventhandler in my other project listens to: **com.checkInService.CheckIn.Service.coreapi.events.CheckIn.CheckedInEvent**. My guess is this is why the eventhandler is not triggered, but im not sure?

All the other configuration for amqp is set correctly, i also connect the ampqmessagesource to my processingroup.

So my question is, is it possible the eventhandler is not triggered because the checkedInEvent got 2 different paths? And if so, how could i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is indeed correct. The payloadType for your EventHandler does not match with the event being emitted. Your EventHandler method registers that it can handle an event of type **com.departureExample.Departure.coreapi.events.CheckIn.CheckedInEvent**. However, the event being sent over rabbit is of type **com.departureExample.Departure.coreapi.events.CheckIn.CheckedInEvent**, for which there is no handler registered.

For any EventHandler it is required that the (super)classes match with what is being emitted, which includes the package name. Some more detailed explanation can be found in the documentation (https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/event-handling/handling-events):

> In all circumstances, at most one event handler method is invoked per listener instance. Axon will search for the most specific method to invoke, using following rules:
>
> 1. On the actual instance level of the class hierarchy (as returned by this.getClass()), all annotated methods are evaluated
> 2. If one or more methods are found of which all parameters can be resolved to a value, the method with the most specific type is chosen and invoked
> 3. If no methods are found on this level of the class hierarchy, the super type is evaluated the same way
> 4. When the top level of the hierarchy is reached, and no suitable event handler is found, the event is ignored.

My suggestion would be to use the fully qualified name of the service emitting the event, which in your case is **com.departureExample.Departure.coreapi.events.CheckIn.CheckedInEvent**. Even if the service you are handling the event in is in a different Bounded Context, you are still handling an event that belongs to the Bounded Context from which it was emitted. Having your package structure reflect makes your code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I added an extra package into my service with the exact same path name, and now everything works fine. Still i find it a bit sloppy to solve it like this, I was thinking about using the coreapi package as a library for all the service. Thanks again for youre answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ViveTech gives you the right pointers that solve the problem, but I'd like to add a small point in here.

The messages, in this case events, are your public API between the applications. As it's public, it could/should be shared among the repositories as a "core API" module/package.

Copying the Event format (aka the implementation) over to both project works, but like you already state, that's a rather sloppy solution.
Sharing a dedicated Core API module would I my mind serve your purpose better.

If you prefer not to share this "implicit schema" (aka the implementation of the event) in a shared library, you can tune the `Serializer` in the framework to use aliases for class names.

The `XStream` instance you can provide to the `XStreamSerializer` gives nice handle for aliases, with the `JacksonSerializer` you'll have to play a little with the `ObjectMapper`.